# Python: Improve accuracy of an keras sequential model

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

While training the model the accuracy percentage of the model is less as compared to the loss, Tried to change the epochs, loss but still the accuracy is not improving.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state = 42)
num_class = len(np.unique(data.IsAddedToReport.values))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(2000, 128,input_length = x.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(196, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_class, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['acc'])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=2, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=10, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Output :

```
Epoch 10/10
17013/17013 [==============================] - 1s 57us/step - loss: 0.6295 - acc: 0.6115 - val_loss: 0.7401 - val_acc: 0.5461
Epoch 00010: val_acc did not improve from 0.55125
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Why are you using and LSTM layer? What's your input data and how does preprocessing look like?

Comment: Loss and accuracy are not in the same range (they do not have the same meaning either), so it makes no sense to compare them directly.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy  - Thanks for the answer, but how we can improve the model accuracy , basically we are using the text sentiment analysis data as input. One column for the text data and another column for the sentimental category data from a CSV file .